# get combinations of sets created after combinations in java

Tags: java

I've come to a dead end and need your help!!
I've managed to get combinations of a list of numbers(Double) that give a specific sum.I also have a hashtable which values are the numbers of the previous list and keys are some Strings eg. numbers(Double)[2.45,2.65,4.67,5.25,2.45,2.65....] and table[(E-40=2.45),(E-45=2.45),(E-56=2.65),(E-34=2.65),(E-24=4.67),(E-14=5.25)....].So after the numbers combinations for a specific sum I get: For sum: 5.10 ---> 2.45 - 2.65 which corresponds to (E-40,E-45) - (E-56,E-34).I would like to get now the combinations of these sets.

eg 
[(E-40)-(E-56)],[(E-40)-(E-34)],
 [(E-45)-(E-56)],[(E-45)-(E-34)]
And here is my code:`

```
public class TestTheCombinations {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> numbers =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2.45,2.45,2.65,2.65,4.67,5.25));
    LinkedHashSet<Double> targets = new LinkedHashSet<Double>() {{
        add(5.10);       
    }};

    for (Double target: targets) {
        Combinations combinations = new Combinations(numbers, target, false);
        combinations.calculateCombinations();
        for (String solution: combinations.getCombinations()) {
           System.out.println(solution);       
        }
    }
}
public static class Combinations {
    private boolean allowRepetitions;
    private int[] repetitions;
    private ArrayList<Double> numbers;
    private Hashtable<String,Double> table;
    private Double target;
    private Double sum;
    private boolean hasNext;
    private Set<String> combinations; 
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param numbers Numbers that can be used to calculate the sum.
     * @param target  Target value for sum.
     */
    public Combinations(ArrayList<Double> numbers, Double target) {
        this(numbers, target, true);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param numbers Numbers that can be used to calculate the sum.
     * @param target  Target value for sum.
     */
    public Combinations(ArrayList<Double> numbers, Double target, boolean allowRepetitions) {
        this.allowRepetitions = allowRepetitions;
        if (this.allowRepetitions) {
            Set<Double> numbersSet = new HashSet<>(numbers);
            this.numbers = new ArrayList<>(numbersSet);
        } else {
            this.numbers = numbers;
        }
        this.numbers.removeAll(Arrays.asList(0));
        Collections.sort(this.numbers);

        this.target = target;
        this.repetitions = new int[this.numbers.size()];
        this.combinations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        this.sum = 0.0;
        if (this.repetitions.length > 0)
            this.hasNext = true;
        else
            this.hasNext = false;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate and return the sum of the current combination.
     *
     * @return The sum.
     */
    private Double calculateSum() {
        this.sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < repetitions.length; ++i) {
            this.sum += repetitions[i] * numbers.get(i);

        }

        return this.sum;
    }

    /**
     * Redistribute picks when only one of each number is allowed in the sum.
     */
    private void redistribute() {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.repetitions.length; ++i) {
            if (this.repetitions[i - 1] > 1) {
                this.repetitions[i - 1] = 0;
                this.repetitions[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        if (this.repetitions[this.repetitions.length - 1] > 1)
            this.repetitions[this.repetitions.length - 1] = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the sum of the next combination. When 0 is returned, there's no other combinations to check.
     *
     * @return The sum.
     */
    private Double next() {
        if (this.hasNext && this.repetitions.length > 0) {
            this.repetitions[0] += 1;
            if (!this.allowRepetitions)
                this.redistribute();
            this.calculateSum();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.repetitions.length && this.sum != 0; ++i) {
                if (this.sum > this.target) {
                    this.repetitions[i] = 0;
                    if (i + 1 < this.repetitions.length) {
                        this.repetitions[i + 1] += 1;
                        if (!this.allowRepetitions)
                            this.redistribute();
                    }
                    this.calculateSum();
                }
            }

            if (this.sum.compareTo(0.0) == 0.0)
                this.hasNext = false;
        }
        return this.sum;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate all combinations whose sum equals target.
     */
    public void calculateCombinations() {
        while (this.hasNext) {
            if (this.next().compareTo(target) == 0)
                this.combinations.add(this.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return all combinations whose sum equals target.
     *
     * @return Combinations as a set of strings.
     */
    public Set<String> getCombinations() {
        return this.combinations;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public String toString() {

          Hashtable<String,Double> table = new Hashtable<String,Double>();
        table.put("E-40",2.45);
        table.put("E-45",2.45);
        table.put("E-56",2.65);
        table.put("E-34",2.65);
        table.put("E-24",4.67);
        table.put("E-14",5.25);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("For SUM " + sum + ": "+"\n");
       StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();

       for (int i = 0; i < repetitions.length; ++i) {

            for (int j = 0; j < repetitions[i]; ++j) {
                Set keys = new HashSet();
                Double value = numbers.get(i);
                for(Map.Entry entry: table.entrySet()){
                    if(value.equals(entry.getValue())){
                        keys.add(entry.getKey()); 
                    }

                } 
                stringBuilder.append(numbers.get(i)+ " Corresponds  WorkCode "+ keys+"\n");

            }

            }
        return stringBuilder.toString() ; 

    }

}



}
```

`

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: When you write “5.10 ---> 2.45 - 2.65”, you mean + right, as in 2.45 + 2.65 = 5.10? Could you also explain what the issue is with your current code, what part of it do you want help with?

Comment: Yes I mean "+" I wrote "-" to seperate the two values.The code as far has no problem,but I need to add code to get extra combinations for the created sets"keys" which are in a loop

Comment: If you use Guava, you can take a look at this method: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-